# `regeneratorRuntime` is not defined when running Jest test

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jestjs, babel-polyfill, babel-jest

The title pretty much explains what I'm facing. I'm trying to test a `React` component that has some state, and I attempt to provide my store to the component in order to get what it needs. When I run the test of the component using Jest, I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

I've determined through some reading that this is caused by `babel-polyfill` or `regenerator-runtime` not being applied correctly to Jest. However, I've tried installing both of those packages and re-running with no change in results. After reading the Jest Github issues page ([Remove auto-inclusion of babel-polyfill #2755](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/2755)), I found out that `babel-polyfill` is not included automatically by Jest as of version 19. My manual installation of that package should have fixed the issue, but it did not. I've included some of the files that I think are relevant

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        ["react-transform", {
          "transforms": [{
            "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
            "imports": ["react"],
            "locals": ["module"]
          }]
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`jest.config`:

```
{
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/webpack-babel-jest",
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-vue-preprocessor",
        ".*": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|css|scss|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__tests__/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue/dist/vue.js"
    },
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["type_parser.spec.js", 
                               "<rootDir>/__tests__/__mocks__/",
                               "__tests__/unit/core/util/type_parser.js",
                               "__tests__/GitlabLoader.test.js"
                               ]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "description": "My Project",
  "scripts": {
    "clean:build": "node ./bin/clean.js createdir",
    "build:html": "node ./bin/buildHtml.js",
    "deployProduction": "node ./bin/deployProduction.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./config/webpack.config.dev.js --hot --inline --progress",
    "serve": "npm run deployProduction&& supervisor --watch ./production-copy src/js/server",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean:build",
    "postbuild": "node ./bin/postBuild.js",
    "rebuild-win": "set BUILD_TYPE=preview& npm run prebuild & npm run build-win & npm run serve",
    "build": "set BUILD_TYPE=final& npm run prebuild & npm run build-win",
    "deploy": "npm run build & npm run serve",
    "build-win": "set NODE_ENV=production & npm run element-build & npm run build-doc & npm run build:html &  webpack -p --config ./config/webpack.config.prod.js --json > webpack.log.json & npm run postbuild",
    "lint": "eslint config src/js/**/*.js",
    "jscs": "jscs src/js/",
    "test": "jest --no-cache --verbose --config=./__tests__/jest.config",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "element-init": "node node_modules/element-theme/bin/element-theme -i src/js/core/ui/element-theme.css",
    "element-build": "node node_modules/element-theme/bin/element-theme -c src/js/core/ui/element-theme.css -o src/js/core/ui/element-theme ",
    "build-doc": "node bin/buildDoc.js ",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my_url"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "my_url"
  },
  "homepage": "my_homepage",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
    "axios": "^0.11.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-standalone": "^6.10.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.0",
    "brace": "^0.8.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.3",
    "cls-bluebird": "^1.0.1",
    "codemirror": "^5.16.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "continuation-local-storage": "^3.1.7",
    "dateformat": "^1.0.12",
    "diff": "^3.0.1",
    "element-theme": "^0.4.0",
    "element-ui": "^1.1.5",
    "express-history-api-fallback": "^2.0.0",
    "filedrop": "^2.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^0.30.0",
    "history": "^2.0.2",
    "humps": "^1.0.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.1.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "jszip": "^3.0.0",
    "jszip-utils": "0.0.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.16.7",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.6",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "normalizr": "^1.0.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.9.1",
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-ace": "^3.5.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.3.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.9.5",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "request-promise": "^3.0.0",
    "reselect": "^2.5.4",
    "save-as": "^0.1.7",
    "showdown": "^1.4.2",
    "three": "^0.79.0",
    "url-pattern": "^1.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-easy-slider": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-loader": "^9.8.1",
    "vue-router": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-slider-component": "^2.0.4",
    "walk": "^2.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@kadira/storybook": "^2.35.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "2.0.0",
    "cheerio": "0.20.0",
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "element-theme-default": "^1.1.5",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint": "^2.13.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.2.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.8.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^19.0.2",
    "jest-cli": "^18.1.0",
    "jest-css-modules": "^1.1.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^2.1.2",
    "jest-vue-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "jscs": "3.0.3",
    "jsdoc-to-markdown": "^2.0.0",
    "jsdom": "8.4.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "3.7.0",
    "postcss-loader": "0.8.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "1.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.11",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.10.3",
    "remotedev": "^0.1.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "3.2.0",
    "storybook-addon-material-ui": "^0.7.6",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "vueify": "^9.4.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-babel-jest": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: *"My manual installation of that package should have fixed the issue, but it did not."* Are you importing the package anywhere? Just installing it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I tried to supply it by doing `import "babel-polyfill"` in my test file, as well as providing it in the `plugins` section of my `.babelrc` with no change.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I used `import "babel-polyfill"` and it solved my problem.

**Update 2020:**
This answer is outdated, `babel-polyfill` is deprecated. Look into [the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) and [the answer by Jero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439821/2024590).

Comment: In what file did you import that?

Comment: I imported it into my actual test and that solved the issue.

Comment: Why didn't adding it globally in *webpack* config file `entry` solved it? importing it for each test isn't ideal

Comment: babel-polyfill is deprecated. Don't use it.  Look here for what happened any why: https://babeljs.io/blog/2019/03/19/7.4.0#core-js-3-7646-https-githubcom-babel-babel-pull-7646. Follow @jero's solution.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I imported it in the `setupTests.js` file

Comment: Install `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime @babel/runtime` and add `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` as a plugin to your babel.config.js. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907975/babel-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-when-using-transform-async-to-generat

Comment: This more generic answer is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267658/1097926

Answer (score 128):

In case you are using a **setupTests.js** file you can import **regenerator-runtime** from there:

```
// setupTests.js

import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import Enzyme from 'enzyme'
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

Enzyme.configure({
  adapter: new EnzymeAdapter()
})
```

Then you can import **setupTests.js** to every test file or better yet, in your **package.json** just add **setupFilesAfterEnv** to the jest config:

```
// package.json

{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./pathToYour/setupTests.js"] 
  }
}
```

Don't forget to install the [regenerator-runtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regenerator-runtime) package:

```
$ yarn add regenerator-runtime --dev
```

There is no need to import the complete babel-polyfill (or @babel/polyfill if Babel ≥ v.7.0.0) that btw has been [deprecated](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) in favor of directly including core-js/stable  and regenerator-runtime/runtime.

Comment: in this case, if you're only introducing it to jest configs, shouldn't regenerator-runtime package be a dev dependency instead?

Comment: Yes @Periback, in the case you are using regenerator-runtime only for testing, you should include it as a dev dependencie. `$ yarn add regenerator-runtime --dev`

Comment: @rafafan2010 could you accept this as the answer? It's a much better answer in 2020. Doesn't involve adding another dependency. Has been supported since node 10, so no need for Babel.

Comment: Adding ``import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'`` did it for me! Thanks!!

Comment: I had to addd that import line to both my `globalSetup` file and as a one-liner file for `setupFilesAfterEnv`. It certainly seems redundant to me but that's how I had to do it for it to work.

Comment: Adding it to globalSetup allowed me to get past the initial error once, then it threw in each individual test suite. Having it imported in my setup file doesn't seem to work or do anything.

Comment: If you aren't already using a setupTests.js file, it may be simpler to add this to your jest.config file:

`setupFilesAfterEnv: [ require.resolve('regenerator-runtime/runtime') ],`

Comment: @MichaelKeenan, the above solution `setupFilesAfterEnv: [ require.resolve('regenerator-runtime/runtime') ]` to jest.config file worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Yeap this `setupFilesAfterEnv: [ require.resolve('regenerator-runtime/runtime') ],` worked for me tks

Answer (score 65):

While importing `babel-polyfill` into each test worked, the [Updated jest docs (v24)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel) suggests setting this in your babel config. If you do this you should no longer need to import `babel-polyfill`. (Personally, I was missing the `targets` option from my `preset-env` config).

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

A word to the wise: specifying `targets` will override any `browserslist` config you have defined (that babel would otherwise use). So in a web project, you'll probably want to create a dynamic `babel.config.js` that is "jest-aware" so that you're only adding `targets` when it's a test environment. See the section titled *"Making your Babel config jest-aware"* in the [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel).

Comment: This didn't solve my issue: only installing `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` and configuring it as a plugin with `"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]` did solve the issue.

Comment: The accepted answers work, but are terrible. The crux of the problem is, as this answer pointed out, correct babel.config.js configuration.

Answer (score 28):

With `babel-core@bridge` installed and `@babel/core@7`:

I solved the issue by adding the plugin [`@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime) and passing to my babel config the following:

```js
{
 // ...
 env: {
   test: {
     // ...
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: **Alternatively**, as [other people commented](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3126#issuecomment-483320742) you can also add only **one option** to `@babel/preset-env`'s config and it should work:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue, also without adding the `regenerator: true` option. Setting `"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]` was enough

Comment: This also worked for me WITHOUT adding the `regenerator: true` option.

Comment: This fixed my issue too, I was using '@bable/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs' and it wasn't working great for me.

Comment: Alternate answer worked for me. Adding `targets` to `@babel/preset-env`

Comment: the second answer can also be found in the jest documentation on using it with babel

Answer (score 20):

Latest solution as of 2 Oct 2019 is to import following in your `setupTests.js` file.

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

`babel-polyfill` is deprecated.

Comment: do we need core js in jest ?

Comment: really helpful, was scratching my head for hours.

Answer (score 20):

For anyone experiencing this problem in 2020, after perusing SO thoroughly, here's information that I found missing from any other answers.

My project is configured as suggested in the [Babel 7.9.0 setup](https://babeljs.io/setup).
After following all of those steps and importing `'@babel/register'` into the top of both my entry points, the ReferenceError persisted.  From the jest documentation, I found this, which fixed my problem:

> // babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

[Jest documentation reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel)

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot in 2021! Using `babel 7.13`

Comment: I agree this is likely the best answer for people running into this issue post-2020.

Comment: While this answer might help some, it didn't solve it for me; what I needed was to [`import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439821/114558)

Answer (score 4):

If someone landed here when searching for the error message but **is not** using Babel then it may be that an old Babel configuration file exists in the project directory since [according to Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel):

> **Making your Babel config jest-aware**
> [...]
> Jest will automatically transform files if a babel configuration
> exists in your project. To avoid this behavior, you can explicitly
> reset the transform configuration option:
>
> ```js
> // jest.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   transform: {},
> };
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Jero's answer. If you're using npm you could do `npm i -D regenerator-runtime` and then `import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';` in your test file.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Vuejs, Vue Jest in Laravel mix and this works for me

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import App from '../App';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
test('it works', () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
});

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
test('should mount without crashing', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(App);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem while testing my endpoint with Supertest in NodeJS:

The problem was

> "Test suite failed to run
>
> ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined "

The solution was:

1. I have installed:

   npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime

Then in .babelrc (besides other options):

I have added

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Why

According to the official Jest docs [`regenerator-runtime` is not longer injected](https://jestjs.io/blog/2019/01/25/jest-24-refreshing-polished-typescript-friendly#breaking-changes) automagically.

> Jest no longer automatically injects regenerator-runtime - if you get errors concerning it, make sure to configure Babel to properly transpile async functions, using e.g. @babel/preset-env. [Related PR](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/7595).

### How

Looking at the PR [a solution](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/7595#issuecomment-549859481) is available:

Install `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` as a dev dependancy

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
```

Install `@babel/runtime` as a dependancy

```
npm install @babel/runtime
```

Then chuck this into your babel configuration (`babel.config.js`):

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [ "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", { "regenerator": true } ]
  ]
}
```