# Babel - regeneratorRuntime is not defined, when using transform-async-to-generator plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, async-await, babeljs

I am not able to setup babel correctly for the usage of async / await.

I am using babel 7 and webpack 4.

I do not want to use babel-polyfill if possible!

My babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": [[
        "@babel/env",
        {"modules": false}
    ]],
    "plugins": [
      "syntax-dynamic-import",
      "transform-async-to-generator"
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
async function init() {
  const loaderData = await initLoader();
  initCmp(loaderData)
    .then(initApi(loaderData.key))
    .catch();
}
init();
```

And Error:

```
refactor.main.js:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at eval (refactor.main.js:18)
    at eval (refactor.main.js:47)
    at Object../client/refactor.main.js (cmp.bundle.js:312)
    at __webpack_require__ (cmp.bundle.js:62)
    at eval (main.js:6)
    at Object../client/main.js (cmp.bundle.js:300)
    at __webpack_require__ (cmp.bundle.js:62)
    at cmp.bundle.js:179
    at cmp.bundle.js:182
```

Answer (score 37):

The latest documentation here is pretty clear:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-runtime

What worked for me is installing the two packages for build and for runtime (the final script for the browser):

`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime`

`npm install --save @babel/runtime`

In the plugin Array of my webpack configuration I just added '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime' without any options. (Please also have a look at the documentation linked above, since some options (that you might find in older tutorials or answers) have been removed.)

```
plugins: [
'@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
]
```

I now can use async functions without errors, and it didn't add much code in the production build.

Comment: When I use this I get an error saying `require is not defined`

Comment: @makkabi can you explain why you install `@babel/plugin[...]` in dev and `@babel/runtime` not?

Comment: @Daniel I followed the docs I linked to above, there is more explaination. As far as I understand, plugin-transform-runtime is used for transpiling the code on build time, so it is only a development dependency and not needed for running the transpiled code.

Comment: I had the same problem in a project with typescript, `esm` modules and jest. I put this 'plugins' array inside `babel.config.json` and it worked.

Comment: thank, this also work in rollup config

Answer (score 2):

You also need the `transform-runtime` plugin, so your .babelrc should ready:

```
{
    "presets": [[
        "@babel/env",
        {"modules": false}
    ]],
    "plugins": [
      "syntax-dynamic-import",
      "transform-runtime",
      "transform-async-to-generator"
    ]
}
```

Note that you'll also need to `npm install --save-dev transform-runtime`

Comment: I needed to do `npm install -D babel-plugin-transform-runtime`, where the difference is the added prefix `babel-plugin-`. Without it I got an error that said _ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-runtime"_ when adding the `"transform-runtime"`-plugin.