# Why is babel-preset-env interfering with transform-async-to-generator?

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs

I was working on an issue that was similar to [Babel - regeneratorRuntime is not defined, when using transform-async-to-generator plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907975/babel-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-when-using-transform-async-to-generat/50993423). I've resolved it, but I am not sure why.

#### My problem

Simply, what I wanted to achieve was to be able to use generator functions and `async`/`await` in my React project where I use Webpack 4 and Babel.

#### My wrong assumption

An initial, but apparently wrong, assumption I made was to think that Babel's `babel-preset-env` was a quick-fix that included *most of* the common, modern features of JS (ES2015-ES2018?)

To use the spread syntax, I had to add `transform-object-rest-spread`; to use generator functions with `yield` I had to add `transform-runtime`.

However, when I wanted to use the `async`/`await` features, I came into the same error as when I tried to use generator functions:

> ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

#### Solved, but not understood

I managed to get around it with [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907975/babel-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-when-using-transform-async-to-generat/50993423), so my `.babelrc`-file looks like:

```
{
  "presets": [
//    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    [
      "transform-runtime",{
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Note that I have commented out the `env`-part of the presets. After commenting it out, my problem seems to be resolved, and I can still use all the other features.

#### The question

- Why does it work now, but not before?
- Also, is `transform-async-to-generator` required to use `async`/`await` with Babel/Webpack; or is there an better (e.g. simpler way)?

Comment: FWIW, object-rest-spread is included in Babel v7's @babel/preset-env—v6 is not getting many new features because development is focused on getting v7 out the door.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'll check which version I'm using.