# regeneratorRuntime is not defined when using async/await

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am getting a

> "regeneratorRuntime is not defined"

when trying to use `async`/`await` in a project.

My `babelrc` file is this currently:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-runtime",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

and my `package.json` is:

```
{
    "name": "****",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "****",
    "main": "index.js",
    "author": "****",
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "yarn build && nodemon server/index.js --ignore dist/ --ignore public/",
        "watch": "parcel watch public/index.html --public-url /",
        "build": "parcel build public/index.html --public-url /",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-validator": "^6.1.1",
        "react": "^16.9.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
        "super-reset-css": "^1.0.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "jest": "^24.8.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.14.11",
        "parcel-bundler": "^1.5.1",
        "sass": "^1.22.9"
    }
}
```

I'm sort of new to configuring babel so not sure what to do here.

Comment: Does this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined) help you out? It contains answers for Babel 6 and 7. I think you are also mixing babel major versions here for `@babel/runtime` and `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` etc. .

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907975/babel-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-when-using-transform-async-to-generat)

Answer (score 8):

I fixed a similar problem using the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907975/babel-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-when-using-transform-async-to-generat)

Try the following in .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ], 
...
```

with the following dev dependencies:
`@babel/plugin-transform-runtime @babel/runtime`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are using `@babel/runtime`.

My set up is `@babel/runtime`, `@babel/core`, `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` and in the `.bablerc` set

```
"plugins": ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
```

I hope this helps.