# Cannot test jest with monaco editor - unexpected token

Tags: jestjs, monaco-editor

Running jest on the application fails with:

```
Details:

/home/**/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js:5
import { EDITOR_DEFAULTS } from './common/config/editorOptions.js';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

> 1 | import * as monaco from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js";
    | ^
  2 | 
  3 | /**
  4 |  * Get create function for the editor.

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/editor-actions.js:1:1)
```

Application has installed packages for `jest` and `babel-jest`.

Babel config:

```
const presets = [
  [
    "@babel/env",
    {
      targets: {
        edge: "17",
        firefox: "60",
        chrome: "67",
        safari: "11.1"
      },
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
      corejs: 3,
    }
  ],
  "@babel/preset-react"
];

const plugins = [
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
  "babel-plugin-styled-components"
];

module.exports = { presets, plugins };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The import statement as suggested in the docs for lazy loading modules from monaco leads to the esm folder, which jest is not familiar with.

```
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js";
```

By default, `babel-jest` would not transform `node_modules` and hence anything referencing the `monaco-editor` would error out. A possible solution is to include `monaco-editor` package into the compilation step by [`transformIgnorePatterns`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string) as mentioned in the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization)

Add these to the jest config:

```
{
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
     "node_modules\/(?!(monaco-editor)\/)"
  ]
}
```

PS: If you are using [`jest-dom`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom), it might start complaining on not implmenting certain features from `monaco-editor`, you can mock it out with:

```
jest.mock("monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround that helped me in that issue (from [here](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor/issues/172#issuecomment-625103606)):

In folder `__mocks__` create file `react-monaco-editor.js` with content:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export default function MonacoEditor() {
  return <div />;
}
```

Comment: I'd tried multiple solutions regarding transformIgnorePatterns and moduleNameMapper, but the only thing that's worked for me is mocking out Monaco.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Jest and Monaco and to make the tests pass I had to:

1. Add a moduleNameMapper for monaco-editor: [#133 (comment)](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor/issues/133#issuecomment-403960502)
2. Configure a setupTests.js like explained here: [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535270/regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-when-running-jest-test/57439821#57439821)

I'm using:

- "jest": "^24.9.0"
- "babel-jest": "24.9",
- "monaco-editor": "^0.20.0"
- "react-monaco-editor": "0.33.0",
- "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^1.8.2",